# Adding new file type (extension) to Xcode4

Tags: xcode4

Is there a way to add extension *.ipp to Xcode4 such that it's treated as a C++ header file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the file inspector. Select the ipp files in the project navigator. Choose C++ Header from the File Type menu in the file inspector.